# Skeleton animation in flashbuilder using only actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I am a noob in flex. I have to animate a hand(upto wrist) for keyboard playing. It has to be done in runtime of the project. For making it more clear, I have saved all the informations in a file about the animation(time, position of fingers etc). How can I animate the fingers(wrist included)? I also need to know how to use a 2D hand with bones in flex.

Thankyou.

Comment: Just to be clear, when you mention "position of fingers", you mean only the position of fingertips?

Comment: Yes. When playing a piano/keyboard, we have to stretch our fingers while our wrist is in the same position. I have to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the source of the files you want to animate, nor did you specify how you want to animate them.

If you just need tochange the X and Y position of an image you can just change the X and Y position of the image.  A tweening library, such as Greensock could help.  I think Flex also has a Move effect that you could use.

If you have the animation created as a SWF, then you can embed the SWF /library element in the Flex app and then use it as a MovieClip.  From the MovieClip you can use play to start an animation and stop to stop the animation.

If you have the animation as a bunch of different bitmaps (Sometimes called a Sprite Sheet) then you can use a blitting implementation to create your animation.  There are plenty of resources out on the web about Blitting in Flex.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Actually, my data are saved in an array. I have to go through the array serially and animate according to those data in RUNTIME. Now if i use images for different finger positions then there will be a lot of combinations of fingers as well as images. So, it would be better for me if I can import a hand with bones and move the bones only. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Without knowing what type of data you have in your array, nor the assets you want to animate; I don't know what additional information I could provide to you.

Comment: Okay. In the array, I have 1.start time of a note being played which is an unsigned int, 2. the finger that will be playing the note which is a string, 3. end time of that note same datatype as start time, 4. the note that is being played in between start and end time(String). The array is also sorted according to the start time. So, all I have to do is move the bones of a hand according to the start and end time. It must be done in runtime.

Comment: @ZayedUpal It sounds like the only information you have--in relation to animation--is the amount of the time the item should animate.  You may possibly have--and I'm not sure--the location of where the image should be.

Comment: Actually, I need a hand with bones and I need to move or rotate the fingers. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: @ZayedUpal What format do you have the hand w/ bones in?  Depending on the format my original answer provides some different techniques for animating it.  I feel like I've already said this

Comment: Actually, I don't have a hand yet. But I can make it through any 3d modelling software or Flash Bone tool. I have seen in this link: "http://blog.flexcommunity.net/?p=16" that a 3d model can be exported to flex. "http://www.webdesigndev.com/flash/flash-bone-tool-tutorial-learn-how-to-use-flash-bone-tool" here flash bone tool is used. How can I use these type of objects and access the bones in flex? :((. Thanks for your patience and helping me out.

Comment: The 3D Features of Flex are beyond my personal knowledge; so I can't provide you more information.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I have done it through papervision3d library in flex. Though it is lot heavier than 2d animation. But I got only this way to do it. Here is the library link: http://code.google.com/p/papervision3d/downloads/detail?name=Papervision3D_1_5.zip&can=2&q=